# Screen capture using java web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, jakarta-ee, screen-capture

Is it possible to capture browser screenshot from a java based web service or java web application with minimal support from JavaScript.

Is there any way capture the same?

Answer (score -2):

### @Joydeep Bhattacharya....try this one

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

...

public void captureScreen(String fileName) throws Exception {

   Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
   ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));

}
```

Comment: If you want to capture the screen on the server, that is. To capture screen on client-side you will have to use a signed Java Web Start application with the correct permissions.

Comment: I agree with@KCWong this will not help capturing the screenshot at the client side. I have already tried this one. As per my understanding JavaScript is the only thing executes in the browser and not the Java code.

Is there any other solution you can think of let me know.